# backbone restful api server return

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, return-value, restful-architecture

I have been trying to look for more information about the restful api, I have found many places talk about what request (method and data) to make for retrieve, create, update object in server, but I couldn't find a place that explains what the server side should return. specifically for backbone.js.

I understand for GET method to a "path/:id", the server would probabily return an stringify json object "{id:1,data:aaa}", or an array of json object. but for create, update and delete, I don't know what the server should return so backbone will acknowledge that server has successfully created the object? I found some api does this:
create successful returns:

{ "createAt":"2014-1-01 11:59pm"}

or failed returns

{ "error":true}

some api does this:

{"sucess":true}
or 
{"error":true}

What is the result that backbone expect?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Backbone` generally expects the following:

- `Create` should return a `JSON` representation of the object
  including an `id` property with a `201` status (Created).
- `Read` should return a `JSON` representation of the object including
  an `id` property with a `200` status (OK).
- `Update` should return a `204` status on success (No content).
- `Destroy` should return a `200` status on success (OK).

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what I needed. So if the returned is anything different, it would be an error?